# SSAS cube: Error while opening a data source view

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, ssas, datasourceview

I got an SQL Server 2012 evaluation edition installed in my Windows 7 laptop. I am trying with an SSAS project. The data source is a database in an instance in the same machine.

I get the following error immediately after creating a Data source view..

```
Error:

TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

An error prevented the view from loading.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) (System.Windows.Forms)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

[image]

```
Error in detail:
===================================

An error prevented the view from loading. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

===================================

The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) (System.Windows.Forms)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.ComponentDiagram.CreateDdsView(Control parentControl)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DataSourceDesignerView..ctor(DataSourceDesigner designer, DataSourceDiagram diagram, IComponent diagramOwnerComponent)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DataSourceDesignerView..ctor(DataSourceDesigner designer)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DataSourceDesigner.CreateDataSourceDesignerView(VsStyleToolBar pageViewToolBar)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.EditorWindow.EnsureViewIsLoaded(EditorView view)
```

Any Idea?
i searched in google. I saw similar errors and feedbacks. But most of them dealing with SQL 2008/2005 edition issues etc..

Here my SSAS designer and SQL server source are 2012. Asking in stack-over flow, after reading many confusing blogs..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you get a successful connection test on your datasouce?

Comment: Yes, The connection to edw is fine, issue is only with dsv

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because someone has manually modified the underlying XMLA code and SSAS can no longer parse it properly.

If the Cube is functioning properly, you can remove your Visual Studio project and create a new one using the existing cube. That's probably the easiest way of dealing with this problem unless you have made significant changes already (even if the issue doesn't have anything to do with XMLA parsing)

Comment: This issue really made me struggle. Finally I uninstalled every component that came along 2008, and reinstalled 2012. Later it started working. You must be correct, may be some files got corrupted.